# issue on focus and select all text in inputs using arrow key

Tags: javascript

i have a js code for navigate on multiple inputs by arrow keys.

but i need to select all after focus input. this code only focus on next tabindex.

```
$(document).ready(function(eOuter) {
    $('#pricelist').on('keydown', 'input', function(eInner) {
        var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        if (eInner.which === 37) { //left
            tabindex++;
            $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();
        }
        if (eInner.which === 38) { //up
            tabindex-=3;
            $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();
        }
        if (eInner.which === 39) { //right
            tabindex--;
            $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').focus();
        }

    });
});
```

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Do not use `tabindex`es like that, and don't hijack default interfaces like this. What if I want to move my cursor one to the left or right to change some input? If your inputs _are_ sequential anyway, you do not need to write the code for this, you _get it for free_. This is an accessibility nightmare... Also, what do you mean with `focus` on all? It might be better to just add `tabindex="0"` to all of the things you want to focus sequentially and let the browser take care of the rest. If this is for accessibility, expect some pissed of users in 3, 2, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(eOuter) {
    $('#pricelist').on('keydown', 'input', function(eInner) {
        var tabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        if (eInner.which === 37) { //left
            tabindex++;
        }
        if (eInner.which === 38) { //up
            tabindex-=3;
        }
        if (eInner.which === 39) { //right
            tabindex--;
        }

        $('[tabindex=' + tabindex + ']').select();
    });
});
```

hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: `.focus()`? Since, "The `HTMLInputElement.select()` method selects all the text in a `<textarea>` element or an `<input>` element with a text field." (Source: MDN)

Comment: the select() here is $.select(), not HTMLInputElement.select() and as far as I understood, he wants to select all the text

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot people still use jQuery.

Comment: no this change only focus of next or prev input. i want selected all text on input after focus, that i can change content very quick.

Comment: are you sure? I tested this and it selects the text in the desired input. I have changed `focus()` with `select()`. Did you do this change?

Comment: yes. I did that exactly same your code. but only do focus

Comment: this change work on firefox, but in chrome not working.